# Will the redis callback be executed in redis and not in my program?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

Let say for example I have the following code:

```
return (long) redisTemplate.execute(new RedisCallback() {
        @Override
        public Object doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
            String redisKey = RedisKeyUtil.getDAUKey(df.format(start), df.format(end));
            connection.bitOp(RedisStringCommands.BitOperation.OR,
                    redisKey.getBytes(), keyList.toArray(new byte[0][0]));
            return connection.bitCount(redisKey.getBytes());
        }
    });
```

Will this doInredis method be executed in the redis cluster and not in my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `RedisTemplate` is just a Springboot helper class that simplifies your Redis data access code, and it is still executing locally in your thread.

If your use case is all related to basic Redis command, you can use Lua (example code [here](https://github.com/wg/lettuce/blob/master/src/test/java/com/lambdaworks/redis/ScriptingCommandTest.java)). However, there is not prefix filtering in list operation, so you probably can also try [`CompletableFuture`](https://lettuce.io/core/5.1.2.RELEASE/api/io/lettuce/core/internal/Futures.html) so your data processing won't block other operations.

Answer (score 0):

You're Java code will not run in Redis. Redis doesn't even know about the JVM so it can't do that at all.

Comment: Is there any way to filter data based on a certain criteria by using the redis template? Let's say I have a key-value pair as so   mykey -> ["johnfernando", ''Danieldario"] and I just want to map the strings in the list whose prefix is Daniel.

Comment: I think there is something called lua scripting in which you can send a script to the redis server. Kindly elaborate on that if possible.

Comment: You can use Lua scripting with Redis. All the details on how it works are in the EVAL command documentation. Note that there are special considerations if you are using clusters with Lua scripts. Everything needs to be in the same shard. https://redis.io/commands/eval